# SQL filter out duplicated from a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query: (SQL Server)

```
SELECT
    sched_ship, loc_desc, 
    bag_no, lotnumber
FROM 
    [My-Table]
WHERE 
    loc_no LIKE '171'
    AND cust_name NOT LIKE 'PCI'
    AND pci_pn NOT LIKE '%TEST%'
ORDER BY sched_ship
```

From this query, I need to remove duplicates and only retain the first result for "bag_no".

IE: This (sched_ship has nothing to do with the sorting I am looking for, disregard it)

```
sched_ship | loc_desc | bag_no | lotnumber
-----------+----------+--------+----------
1-05-2014  | loc 1    | G123   | 2345-35
3-22-2014  | loc 1    | H347   | 9583-68
4-16-2014  | loc 1    | G123   | 2745-34
4-25-2014  | loc 1    | J846   | 5726-90
4-26-2014  | loc 1    | G123   | 1756-28
5-12-2014  | loc 1    | J846   | 2847-68
```

Returns this: (sched_ship has nothing to do with the sorting I am looking for, disregard it)

```
sched_ship | loc_desc | bag_no | lotnumber
-----------+----------+--------+----------
1-05-2014  | loc 1    | G123   | 2345-35
3-22-2014  | loc 1    | H347   | 9583-68
4-25-2014  | loc 1    | J846   | 5726-90
```

(sched_ship has nothing to do with the sorting I am looking for, disregard it)

All I want is to take my query results and then further filter out any rows with duplicate "bag_no"s.

Comment: MIN(sched_ship)..GROUP BY bag_no

Comment: It looks like you want the record with the earliest sched_ship value per bag_no. Is that your intent?

Comment: No, the date is irrelevant. I simply want to strip out any rows where the bag_no is the same and only leave the first one. Im trying to simplify the actual results for the sake of the question as its far larger then presented here.

My goal is only to remove duplicate bag_no results leaving only the first.

Comment: SQL Server, sorry for not mentioning.

Comment: You mean like an ID number for each entry? No, there are none.

Comment: Add a `MIN()` on all columns except bag_no  and before order by use `GROUP BY bag_no`

Comment: I get an error saying that sched_ship is not contained in an aggregate function or group by clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `row_number()` and then selecting the first record using `where`:

```
select sched_ship, loc_desc, bag_no, lotnumber
from (SELECT sched_ship, loc_desc, bag_no, lotnumber,
             row_number() over (partition by bag_no order by sched_ship asc) as seqnum
      FROM [My-Table]
      WHERE loc_no LIKE '171' AND cust_name NOT LIKE 'PCI' AND pci_pn NOT LIKE '%TEST%'
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
ORDER BY sched_ship;
```

`row_number()` assigns a sequential number to a group of rows starting at 1.  The group is defined by the `partition by` clause, so everything with the same `bag_no` is in the same group (in this case).  The order is based on the `order by` clause, so the first row by `sched_ship` has a value of 1.  The `where` clause chooses this row.

EDIT:

You can do this with a CTE:

```
with t as (
        SELECT sched_ship, loc_desc, bag_no, lotnumber,
               row_number() over (partition by bag_no order by sched_ship asc) as seqnum
        FROM [My-Table]
        WHERE loc_no LIKE '171' AND cust_name NOT LIKE 'PCI' AND pci_pn NOT LIKE '%TEST%'
       )
select sched_ship, loc_desc, bag_no, lotnumber
from t
where seqnum = 1
ORDER BY sched_ship;
```

Comment: For whatever reason, it seems to have an extreme hatred with sub-queries. It says "Incorrect syntax near ')'"

Comment: Edit: You first suggestion worked this time around. I don't know why, but it does now. You have answered my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this buddy...

```
SELECT sched_ship, loc_desc, bag_no, lotnumber 
FROM [My-Table] 
WHERE sched_ship 
IN (SELECT MIN(sched_ship) FROM [My-Table] GROUP BY bag_no)
```

Comment: Invalid Syntax at "IN".

A reminder that the ship date has absoludly nothing to do with anything for what I am filtering by with this issue. My query is filtered by oldest to newest date, but that is it. There is no relation between bag_no and sched_ship.